# Multiple Rows to single Columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like so:

```
id int not null,
colName varchar(50) not null,
info varchar(max)
```

Sample data:

```
id  colName    info

1   firstname  Mary
1   surname    Jones
2   firstname  John
2   surname    Smith
3   firstname  Bat
3   surname    Man
```

I would like to be able to create a view (or something) so that I can do something like this:

```
SELECT firstname
FROM viewOrSomething
```

which would output, for the sample data above, the following:

```
firstname

Mary
John
Bat
```

and this

```
SELECT surname, firstname
FROM viewOrSomething
```

which would output, for the sample data above, the following:

```
surname firstname

Jones   Mary
Smith   John
Man     Bat
```

Can this be done?  How would I do it?

Ideally a solution that copes with any number of different values in the colName column, but I'll settle for just two if that points me in the right direction.

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) - 11.0.7462.6 (X64) 
    Jan  5 2018 22:11:56 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

*EDIT*

The given answers don't give me what I want - this is not a duplicate question, I have already looked at answers like this and they are too rigid.  They don't allow for column names that are not "firstname" and "surname".  They don't allow for other than a fixed number of columns.

Also don't give me the option to do things like:

```
SELECT surname, firstname
FROM viewOrSomething
```

as per my original request.

Comment: Have you tried the pivot function? Will only work inside a view with limited, well-known values (not dynamic). A dynamic pivot will generate a column for each different value of colName, but you can't use it on a function or view as it requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: Note that as soon as you have a dynamic number of columns, you can't use this in a `VIEW`. you would have to use a Stored procedure. If you try, and fail, to implement these methods (there are plenty more examples on [how to dynamically pivot data on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Pivot+rows+sql+server+dynamic+%22cross+tab%22&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Pivot+rows+sql+server+dynamic+%22cross+tab%22)) then you would be better off posting a new question, showing your attempt(s) and explain why they didn't work.

Comment: Follow the linked posts, or use the working [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=53c617ca23ddfcbd3a62076d5234766e) for the your post.